# Automatic detection of technical patterns such as Head and Shoulder, Flag, Wedge or Double Top

Tags: algorithmic-trading, technical-analysis, algorithm

To my understanding, Ta-Lib does not detect technical patterns such as Head and Shoulder, Flag, Wedge or Double Top.

Is there any automatic way to detect such technical patterns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Designing scanning logic of past history for probability of common market pattern re-occurrences in single timeframe](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61433/designing-scanning-logic-of-past-history-for-probability-of-common-market-patter)

Comment: TA and QF are two distinct things, see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/43338/70573).

Comment: @Alex, agree. 
The objective is to develop an algebraic representation of TA concepts and utilize them as points of confluence.

Comment: @DimitriVulis, the post is in a right direction, but what is the algorithm to detect top nodes,  so being able to model them like 4,-1,2,-2,1,-1? I am hoping to have a complete answer this time.

Comment: Allan: The link below is a nice paper explaining how the use of moving averages ( MACD is in the appendix ) is really just a comparison of shorter term returns and longer term returns. So, although, it doesn't answer your question, I found it enlightening because it shows how, atleast in some cases, TA is not all voodoo and magic. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2604942

Comment: Thank you @markleeds. The article is very helpful.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. It helped me to realize that there is more of an overlap between TA and quant than people give TA credit for. It's not always voodoo !!!!